# FormRequest Scrapy trouble when loggin in

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to retrieve info from [AliceWeb2](http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br). For do this, I need to login, but I can't. I put my user, pass and search in the inspect tool from Google Chrome for a page that has the Request Method: POST, as showed below:

[image: Network Tool].

So, using the following code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy import Request


class AliceWeb2(Spider):
    name = "login"

    # Start on the welcome page
    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(
                "http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br//usuario/login/",
                callback=self.parse_welcome)]

    # Post welcome page's first form with the given user/pass
    def parse_welcome(self, response):
        formdata = {'logUser': 'rtadewald',
                    'logPass': '123'}
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=formdata)
```

I got this:
[image: Scrapy CMD's bug]

Comment: instead of a screen shot, post your error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `yield` instead of `return`

and whenever you are trying to mimic a request, just open Dev Tools, and copy cURL of that URL, and then go to this https://curl.trillworks.com/ website, and get your Python code, and then re-use that code into Scrapy.

[image]

```
class AliceWeb2(Spider):
    name = "login"

    # Start on the welcome page
    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            'Origin': 'http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Referer': 'http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br/usuario/recuperar-senha',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'DNT': '1',
        }

        yield Request('http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br//usuario/login?tx_usuario=ABC&tx_senha=ABC', callback=self.parse_welcome, headers=headers, data=data, method="POST")

    def parse_welcome(self, response):
        #do something here
```

**EDIT 1:**
When I observed request in Dev Tools, I saw those parameters were being sent, see `FORM DATA` in screenshot.

(another tip):
Check `preserver log` so you can see requests sent in previous page in case if the website redirects you to some other page after login.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

One little question, how'd you know that you should make a request to **'http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br//usuario/login?tx_usuario=ABC&tx_senha=ABC'** instead of simply **http://aliceweb.mdic.gov.br//usuario/login**

Thanks!

EDIT 1: By checking "Preserve log", I'm not able to see the Form Data as you see. Is there any other option?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBwR2.png

Comment: @RodrigoSoaresTadewald that is impossible ... you should see those parameters ... what chrome version are you using? it should show those parameters in all chrome version BTW .... please try to input incorrect user/pass combination and see if they show up